# Convert .docx to Html without CSS with Docx4j

Tags: ckeditor, docx4j

I'm trying to "upload" an html-converted .docx file into a CKEditor. So far, the convertion from .docx to html is nearly perfect and I'm able to pass the code from Java(Spring/Maven) to  my webapp(ZK framework, using native CKEditor and JavaScript).

The problems I've had so far revolve around the fact that the loaded text is either half-formatted or not formatted at all, and that's the actual reason I'm working in this (To avoid loss of format present by copy-pasting). I've managed to find the reason of this behaviour: CK likes HTML tags OR won't use multiple styles per container (ie. style="font-weight: bold" is Ok, but style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold" isn't, it will pick one or another) and Docx4j uses inline styling for formating because of XHTML (As far as I've read).

After that I tried to force the styles in CKEditor by the config file, but that wasn't the solution as one element will overwrite the another, resulting in only one style being used.
With all that, I decided to manipulate a test docx (It's literally a "hello world" line bold, with italics and underline), converted it and forced the tags b, i and u on the resulting HTML file through Java. The result was the desired one.

Now my focus is to config docx4j so it uses **tags instead of inline css**, as so far it's the "easiest" solution and I liked the resulting html from it. After reasing some more I came across an [old class](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-html-oldschool/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/html/HtmlExporterOldSchool.java) with a method that (by name) will do that, but it's not present in my imported library. I tried both, [new](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtml.java) and [old](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtmlDeprecated.java) methods to convert to html but the results are the same.

Is there a setting or a way to let docx4j (v8.2.3 reference) know that I want html tags instead of css styles? I've seen the examples and looked into the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.docx4j/docx4j/latest/index.html), but it's a bit outdated and didn't really helped me that much. This seems to be the only way to do this, or build my own parser, which is simply not an option due time constraints.

Thanks!